# How can I run two separate state trees on one angular application?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a web application that uses `angular-ui-router` 0.x to manage its SPA state navigation. Additionally, we have a reusable component that uses a separate angular application (manually `angular.bootstrap()`'d) and thus a separate `angular-ui-router` instance to manage its own state, UI, and transitions.

This works well for now--the two "applications" have their own `$stateProvider` instances with completely independent state, and the main application can simply spawn the secondary component as a modal with minimal issues.

However, we've started hitting edge scenarios where running two Angular applications on the same page doesn't work so well--as well as having concerns about sharing state between the main application and this sub-component.

Is there any way to have multiple independent `ui-router` instances, `$stateProviders`, or state trees in a single AngularJs application? Or any alternatives to ui-router 0.x which don't have this limitation?